# open bin file and convert ascii to hex

Tags: python, io, python-3.x, binary

I want to open some data from a bin file

```
import io
data=io.open('bpsk_2m_b11.rd16','rb').read()
print (data)
```

But there appear to be some ASCII symbols, e.g. (i mean '{' and 'k','w' )

b'\xde{\x1d\x86\xa0\x81kw\xbc\x8a'

I'm fine with the whole formating thing but how can I replace those ASCII symbols with hex? Or should I use some other mode to read this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working fine, `b'{'` is just another way of writing `b'\x7b'`:

```
>>> b'{' == b'\x7b'
True
```

You can create a character string of only escapes with the following helper method:

```
import binascii
def to_byte_escapes(b):
   return ''.join('\\x' + binascii.hexlify(byte) for byte in b)
```

Then you'll get:

```
>>> print(to_byte_escapes(b'\xde{\x1d\x86\xa0\x81kw\xbc\x8a'))
\xde\x7b\x1d\x86\xa0\x81\x6b\x77\xbc\x8a
```

Comment: yea, I realize that, but its more like a formating issue - how to make it appear like \x7b not {. 
edit::
the file is very long and I need all the data in it to be in hex, the point is how to change those particular ASCII signs to hex/open this file that way it shows only hex

Comment: @user1827025 Updated with a solution that uses [`binascii.hexlify`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify). Note that "Python byte escapes" is a pretty weird data interchange format.

Comment: thanks a lot - got some problems with implementing that in python 3.x (since I just got out 2.x), but now its ok.